# How can I update all values in a table with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

i want to update all, when i click on the update all button, i want all the `CHANTIERS` of each line checked in the list `SALARIES` update by value selected in dropdown list.for example if i choose 1 in dropdown list and when i click button update all i want all values `chantiers` of `salaries` cheked updating to 1.

hi, i want to update all, when i click on the update all button

**index.php**

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head> 
        <title>How to update multiple row with checkbox? </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-confirmation/1.0.5/bootstrap-confirmation.min.js"></script>
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <h3>How to update multiple row with checkbox using Ajax?</h3>
        <div class="form-group col-md-3  ">
            <select class="form-control" id="chantier">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-success update-all" data-url="">Update All</button>
        <button style="margin: 5px;" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete-all" data-url="">Delete All</button>
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <th><input type="checkbox" id="check_all"></th>
                <th>S.No.</th>
                <th>nom & prenom</th>
                <th>cin</th>
                <th>matricule</th>
                <th>chantier</th>
            </tr>
            <tr id="tr_id">
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" data-id="id"></td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>jack chim</td>
                <td>pa130191</td>
                <td>2925019599</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="tr_id">
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" data-id="id"></td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>najib mareouk</td>
                <td>pa454547</td>
                <td>2925019988</td>
                <td>1</td>
            </tr>
    
        </table>
    </div> 
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#check_all').on('click', function(e) {
             if($(this).is(':checked',true))  
             {
                $(".checkbox").prop('checked', true);  
             } else {  
                $(".checkbox").prop('checked',false);  
             }  
            });
             $('.checkbox').on('click',function(){
                if($('.checkbox:checked').length == $('.checkbox').length){
                    $('#check_all').prop('checked',true);
                }else{
                    $('#check_all').prop('checked',false);
                }
             });
            $('.update-all').on('click', function(e) {
                var idsArr = [];  
                $(".checkbox:checked").each(function() {  
                    idsArr.push($(this).attr('data-id'));
                });  
                if(idsArr.length <=0)  
                {  
                    alert("Please select atleast one record to update.");  
                }  else { 
                    alert("some idea for update all");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    </html>
```

Comment: Please don't repeat the same text twice. Instead explain more in detail what the problem is, what the expected outcome is, what you get instead.

Comment: What you want to update? i did not understand what you want exactly.

Comment: @trincot  thx for answer but,even I explain but he asks me more detail, if for that I repeat sentences

Comment: @AnkurMishra i want to update chantier with value select

Comment: The system asks for more details, because ... you *need* to provide more details. See my first comment on what you should provide in addition. Circumventing the system is not going to give you appreciation here. Downvotes are not far away.

Comment: I think the confusion lies in the statement "line checked by the value selected in the select field". Please revise your post to elaborate on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head> 
        <title>How to update multiple row with checkbox? </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-confirmation/1.0.5/bootstrap-confirmation.min.js"></script>
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <h3>How to update multiple row with checkbox using Ajax?</h3>
        <div class="form-group col-md-3  ">
            <select class="form-control" id="chantier">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-success update-all" data-url="">Update All</button>
        <button style="margin: 5px;" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete-all" data-url="">Delete All</button>
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <th><input type="checkbox" id="check_all"></th>
                <th>S.No.</th>
                <th>nom & prenom</th>
                <th>cin</th>
                <th>matricule</th>
                <th>chantier</th>
            </tr>
            <tr id="tr_id">
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" data-id="id"></td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>jack chim</td>
                <td>pa130191</td>
                <td>2925019599</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="tr_id">
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" data-id="id"></td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>najib mareouk</td>
                <td>pa454547</td>
                <td>2925019988</td>
                <td>1</td>
            </tr>
    
        </table>
    </div> 
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#check_all').on('click', function(e) {
             if($(this).is(':checked',true))  
             {
                $(".checkbox").prop('checked', true);  
             } else {  
                $(".checkbox").prop('checked',false);  
             }  
            });
             $('.checkbox').on('click',function(){
                if($('.checkbox:checked').length == $('.checkbox').length){
                    $('#check_all').prop('checked',true);
                }else{
                    $('#check_all').prop('checked',false);
                }
             });
            $('.update-all').on('click', function(e) {
                let selected = $('#chantier').val();
                
                if ($(".checkbox:checked").length > 0)
                {
                  $(".checkbox:checked").each(function() {  
                    $(this).closest('tr').find('td:last-child').html(selected);
                  });
                } else {
                  alert("Please select atleast one record to update."); 
                }
                                
            });
        });
    </script>
    </html>
```